# Select on track of a midi file for playing with timidity

Tags: midi

```
$ timidity file.mid
```

Recognizes the 4 tracks of my midi file:

```
Track name: soprano
Track name: alto
Track name: tenor
Track name: bass
```

Timidity plays them all at the same time. Is it also possible to play only one or two tracks at the same time?
I checked the man page, but I could not find such an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look at the `-Q` option.

For example, the format `-Q 0,-3` would mute all channels, but not the number 3.

Comment: Channels and tracks are not the same thing in MIDI files!  This answer will mute *channel* 3, but that  doesn't answer the question.  I also can't find a way to play selected tracks using timidity.  As far as I can tell, the best option is to use sequence software such as Rosegarden or Muse.

Comment: @AlexanderHanysz: the OP intended the channel, given that track is not a term that has a specific meaning in MIDI terminology. Anyway the OP accepted the answer, and this mean that I answered his question.

Comment: Track does have a very specific meaning in the MIDI file format specification--a couple of minutes' work with your favourite search engine will provide the details.  The tracks listed by the timidity output are the same as the MIDI file tracks, and are not usually the same as channels (although it is possible to make a MIDI file with each channel in a separate track--perhaps your answer helped the OP because of a lucky coincidence).

Comment: @AlexanderHanysz: are you sure the OP intended track and not channel? I'll leave you to your beliefs.